# How to read the following table of data?

Tags: categorical-data, data-visualization, dataset, tables

I have downloaded the following table from https://www.ons.gov.uk for car rental market.

Does `Turnover (£000s)` mean the the values should be multiplied by 1000?

I.e. the size on the london car rental market is 4,908,606,000?

That seems too large if that's the case?

[image]

Comment: What period of time does this cover and how is the "London" market defined?  A little Googling suggests the UK market is £15 Bn per annum.

Comment: That's a good question. It just says "data as of 2019" - https://www.ons.gov.uk/businessindustryandtrade/business/activitysizeandlocation/adhocs/12090carrentalbyregion

Comment: @whuber wrt regions, another ONS page mentions "Quarterly economic activity within the countries of the UK (England, Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland) and the nine English regions (North East, North West, Yorkshire and The Humber, East Midlands, West Midlands, East of England, London, South East, and South West)."

Comment: This https://www.ons.gov.uk/businessindustryandtrade/business/activitysizeandlocation refers to "a snapshot of the Inter-Departmental Business Register" so I guess the numbers are taken from that register in March 2019 and turnover is annual. There is more info on that register at https://www.ons.gov.uk/aboutus/whatwedo/paidservices/interdepartmentalbusinessregisteridbr

Answer (score 1):

The table you're referring to is at https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/businessindustryandtrade/business/activitysizeandlocation/adhocs/12090carrentalbyregion/ah679.xls

At first I agreed that it looks as if "£'000s" is wrong, suggesting the turnover is in tens of billions. On second thought a quick Google found [BVRLA Industry Outlook](https://www.bvrla.co.uk/uploads/assets/uploaded/b4657f34-baaf-4cc3-83543b20bbf2c700.pdf) which says (p2)

> The vehicle rental and leasing industry supports over 465,000 jobs, adds £7.6bn in tax revenues and contributes £49bn to the UK economy each year.

... suggesting tens of billions is correct.